# Is using test factories in Laravel an anti pattern?

Tags: laravel, integration-testing, anti-patterns

On this slide :

[image]

Sandiz Metz [talks about how we should test from the outside](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=URSWYvyc42M) without knowing anything about what goes inside the SUT.

I think her talk is focused on the unit tests, not so much about integration tests, but that still made me wonder...could using the [factories](https://laravel.com/docs/master/database-testing#using-factories) in Laravel be an anti-pattern ?

It seems to me that using these factories mean I know how the database data has to be for the SUT to complete its task.

For example, say a user has to be able to edit his profile. With factories, I could do this :

```
/** @test */
public function the_user_can_update_his_profile()
{
    $user = factory(User::class)->create();

    // ACT

    // ASSERT
}
```

But that knowledge seems to be far too deep and detailed. I have to know how to create a properly registered user. Following the idea of staying in the outside world, shouldn't I instead use an object that already exist to prepare the data for my tests ?

```
/** @test */
public function the_user_can_update_his_profile()
{
    $userRepository = app(UserRepository::class);
    $user = $userRepository->register('email@email.com', 'password123');

    // ACT

    // ASSERT
}
```

Going even further, how do I know this is the right way to do it ? Shouldn't I simply call the route that a user will use to register ?

```
/** @test */
public function the_user_can_update_his_profile()
{
    $response = $this->json('POST', route('register_user'), ['email' => 'email@email.com', 'password' => 'password123']);
    $userRepository = app(UserRepository::class);
    $user = $userRepository->find($response['userId']);

    // ACT

    // ASSERT
}
```

But that (extreme) solution could also do tons of unnecessary other things (e.g. sending a confirmation email). It also needs the register route to work.

What did you experience as being the cleanest solution for a complicated project ?

Comment: You've literally opened a gigantic can of worms there. Your issue is that you're not writing a *unit* test in your last example. You're writing an *integration* test for that route, and testing every component interacting with your request along the way.

Comment: Does it mean the point of testing from an outside point of view is invalid with integration testing ?

Comment: Nah, it's more complicated than this. The *type* of test you're writing dictates both your goal and your methodology. I'll write it up in an answer, I'm going to go way over 500 characters on this.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, you're mistaking the purpose and scope of a **unit test** and an **integration test**, and from this comes the confusion. Let's start with your "test":

```
/** @test */
public function the_user_can_update_his_profile()
{
    $response = $this->json('POST', route('register_user'), ['email' => 'email@email.com', 'password' => 'password123']);
    $userRepository = app(UserRepository::class);
    $user = $userRepository->find($response['userId']);

    // ACT

    // ASSERT
}
```

This is an integration test. You are testing a "remote" route (okay, it's internal, but you're still testing every single component along the way). An integration test is perfect to confirm that business logic was implemented properly and that the route behaves as expected; it goes through its path from start to completion, testing every interaction between components and the logic in the controller+view itself.

This is all fine and good, but it doesn't really help us that much. We're still blind regarding testability of components themselves. This is where unit testing comes in.

Assume you have a class as follows:

```
<?php
class Foo {
  public $value = 0;
  public function __construct($value) {
    $this->value = (int)$value;
  }
  public function getRemainder(int $item) {
    return $this->value % $item;
  }
}
```

You may very well end up using this class in one of your controllers; the point of unit testing this is to assert that:

- the constructor **does** store the right value (as an integer)
- the `isModulo` method **does** what it says on the tin.

To do so, we might write the following test:

```
public function isActualModuloClass() {
  $modulo = new Foo(5);
  $modulo_float = new Foo(2.3);
  assert($modulo->value == 5, "Integer modulo constructor works");
  assert($modulo_float->value == 2, "Float modulo casts to integer properly");
  assert($modulo->getRemainder(5) == 0, "Modulo 5%5 is 0");
  assert($modulo->getRemainder(4) == 1, "Modulo 5%4 is 1");
}
```

And sure enough, we've tested every single method, every single branch of our component **in isolation**. This is a unit test.

It gets messier with classes that interact with other objects, but when structured properly, it is very easy to leverage tools to inject mock copies of objects in order to be able to stub out interactions. When your code touches multiple things at once in an unclean fashion, your tests tend to end up a being gargantuan mess.

The talk you linked is about these tests, and ways to make them not be the fragile mess they tend to be in badly thought-out codebases. In theory, the author is right as well - you start from objects without dependencies, test those, then gradually go up assuming the *contracts* being established by those are sane and tested, and you work your way up the pyramid. In practice, it's very hard to do when the code is written with testing as an afterthought.

Comment: Hmm you didn't really answer my question though. I know the difference between unit testing and integration testing, and I also use TDD pretty much every day. My question was focused on how should needed data be prepared during integration testing, as I thought writing data directly in databases was an indication that I might know too much about what's needed there. So I wanted some advice on that thought.

Comment: @SteveChamaillard Last paragraph. In this case, you'd unit test the model layer, which should not require actual data. Then, you'd stub that out and trap the calls you expect your code to make. For instance, when setting the user's password you'd expect a call to `$model->setPassword()`. You don't actually care about the inner logic (since you tested that elsewhere) - you just care that it happened.

Comment: So you say I should be mocking everything being called during my integration tests ? That feels like I'll just rewrite the implementation in the form of a test. By the way your last paragraph is very true for unit testing, I don't see how it applies to integration testing (but I might be wrong).

Comment: @SteveChamaillard you definitely should not be testing stuff on **real** data, if that's what you're asking. Whether you're (for example, as I tend to do) spinning up a SQLite in-memory database to test things or you're mocking the entire call is down to you. Integration tests tend to be a lot looser in terms of "what is right" and "what is wrong", as a lot of it depends on the interaction between components and complexity of the application.

Comment: I guess you could stub the entire DB layer out on an integration test, though. It'd be messy but it'd work. As stated, I typically curate a data set on a sqlite database, run my tests, then compare the dataset with my "expected" values. Calls to outside APIs (like twilio, discord, etc) are stubbed and trapped.

Comment: Ok we agree on this 100%. I do the same thing, I have a SQLite in-memory database that I use for my integration tests. But at the start of the test, this database is empty and is only made of the structure of tables. I still don't know what's the cleanest option to prepare needed data at the start of the test ? Writing data directly in the database, or using domain objects to create this data ? These are two very different options imo, that's what I wanted my question to be focused on :)